# Why did the manufacturer fit a usb port on my e-bike battery when it is not connected?

Tags: electric-bike, folding-bicycle, battery, electric-power

I have a Viking gravity e-bike with an internal frame battery pack which has a usb port included. Thing is, I found out that it wasn't working even though its a brand new bicycle. So I investigated and uncovered it wasn't wired up at all inside the battery pack. There weren't even any adapter/wires available for this feature to get connect to. Is this a flaw on my bike or has anyone else noticed this problem?

Why to go through the process to fit something that is not going to be connected up to work? I'd like to see/hear any views as surely this is a massive waste of money on the manufacturer's behalf and also annoying to the customers.

Comment: Did the specifications for the model you have include a USB port?.  If so, its a fault, if not, it may be that the model or two up has it connected, and its cheaper and easier to ship all frames with the port than have two frame variations.

Comment: The specs I find online for this bike do not mention a USB port as a feature.  Your most authoritative answer will come from the maker, Hero Cycles in India.      https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viking_Cycle_Company which leads to http://www.herocycles.com/

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't fully answer the question but I've found a (replacement?) battery [online](https://www.aliexpress.us/item/3256805669995723.html?src=google&aff_fcid=14f4a19344e14af59fb8e468e0fe1ed9-1702908406039-01325-UneMJZVf&aff_fsk=UneMJZVf&aff_platform=aaf&sk=UneMJZVf&aff_trace_key=14f4a19344e14af59fb8e468e0fe1ed9-1702908406039-01325-UneMJZVf&terminal_id=c63cb7cc11b54f68a411ae4e20f26a89&afSmartRedirect=y&gatewayAdapt=vnm2usa#nav-review) that seems to be compatible to the *Viking Gravity* based on its product description:

> Compatible with ebike type Viking Gravity ; Dawest Arc 2, Powabike F100,Powabike West hill, Link Apollo Smart S2.Chrisson EF1 / DeHawk / Emina Bike/Populo Curve eBike.Compatible with ebike type Viking Gravity ; Dawest Arc 2, Powabike F100,Powabike West hill, Link Apollo Smart S2.Chrisson EF1 / DeHawk / Emina Bike/Populo Curve eBike

One of the provided product images identifies this as a *charge port* for external devices

[image]

If this looks like on your battery, you at least got an explanation what the port was meant for. I've found another [battery pack](https://electropapa.com/de/akku-passend-fuer-fischer-faltrad-fr18-e-bike-8700mah-36v-888402741-522412?gad_source=1&gclid=CjwKCAiA-P-rBhBEEiwAQEXhH98nkCBZEqA-2MBtGYPP-4XR5ADuk6XdxJxx3jOK-brN7UtreMqN1BoCS2IQAvD_BwE) that looks similar. Actually, Google brought it up when looking for *Viking Gravity battery* and it seems to be a common battery for a range of foldable e-bikes. The German description there also states it is meant for use as a power bank, so I'm pretty sure that's what it is.

Why it isn't connected is probably something to be asked to the supplier/manufacturer, reasons might range from counterfeit to somebody just having a bad day at the assembly line.

Since this was posted in Q3 of 2020, it might also be due to component shortage during the COVID pandemic, i.e. charging electronics missing and some batches just getting assembled without charging/power bank functionality, somebody made a choice between gluing the original USB port and just leaving it in place.

USB A female [connector](https://www.aliexpress.us/item/2255799859365059.html?gatewayAdapt=glo2usa4itemAdapt) costs virtually nothing, so why bother changing the design - in the automotive industry, cars are often shipped with hardware/software features disabled rather than being "removed" because it is more cost-efficient to only have one design and no extra steps in the manufacturing process. In most cases it is only wiring but there are example of parts that cost way more than an USB port being effectively useless in cars, for example whole ECUs, sensors, etc...

*(That's pure speculation but stranger things have happened...)*

Answer (score 0):

A coworker has a new ebike conversion in the office, and the lights are simply 5V lamps with a USB-A male connector on the end of a wire.   The lamps are intended to run off the bike's internal battery, which has two USB outlets for this purpose.

Could be your battery has a similar intention, to run USB items.

As to why the internals aren't there, that may have been an optional extra at time of purchase, or a simple oversight, or possibly your bike is a knockoff of a better bike but has had as many things left out as possible for price saving.

Comment: It is a common theme from the car industry that (cheap) things are installed but not wired up or activated via software but it is still cheaper to ship basic wiring for unused features than having two separate designs or variations in the manufacturing process. On my 2000s E90 3-series BMW, it only cost 300€ to retrofit cruise control, all the electronics are there, you just needed to fit the additional lever and do some coding in the firmware.

Comment: @DoNuT good point.  A worse example is brands that ship all the hardware installed in all cars, but charge a fee to enable it.

Comment: _cough_ Tesla _cough_, @Criggie

Answer (score 0):

When doing GPS navigation with mobile, screen always on and bright, the battery of the phone may run out well before the journey is finished. Hence I understand why do they put an USB power source on a bicycle.

As to why not connected... In my flat, I had some sensors of my heating system not connected. There are sensors mounted on the walls, wire ends hang in the air. And when "professionals" assembled a computer to me, they rammed the alluminum heat sink with huge force into the PCB of the video card. Knowing aluminum conducts electricity was probably too much for them.

Do not look for explanations too deeply.